# Query whether CUDA device supports 32-bit or 64-bit addressing

Tags: cuda

I would like to discover, at runtime, whether a CUDA GPU supports 32-bit or 64-bit addressing. For context, I'm using LLVM to generate PTX at runtime, and need to know whether to set the target triple to `nvptx` or `nvptx64`.

There doesn't appear to be a direct query for this via `cuDeviceGetAttribute`, but is there some other query or heuristic that can give me this information?

Comment: all CUDA GPUs supported by current CUDA toolkits (7.x or newer) support either 32-bit or 64-bit addressing.  It's determined at application load time by the type of application/process (host and device should be in agreement) that has been compiled.  If the initialization of the cuda context is performed from a 64-bit process, a 64-bit context should be created.  If the initialization of the cuda context is performed from a 32-bit process, a 32-bit context should be created.  Therefore, although I haven't tried it, I think a simple `sizeof(void *)` should be sufficient to differentiate.

Answer (score 2):

64 bit addressing is a hard requirement for unified addressing to work. Also all NVidia GPUs that are 64 bit addressing capable do support unified addressing. So testing if unified addressing is supported for a given device context also tells if 64 bit addressing is supported.

The field [`unifiedAddressing`](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-runtime-api/structcudaDeviceProp.html#structcudaDeviceProp_107b0114cefb43da05e05c65ec859542c) of struct cudaDevice prop queried with [`cudaGetDeviceProperties`](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-runtime-api/group__CUDART__DEVICE.html#group__CUDART__DEVICE_1g1bf9d625a931d657e08db2b4391170f0) gives that information.